# Click on element and move to another page with dropdown based on element that clicked in first page

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make simple effect but i don't know what is the perfect way to do this. In first page i have six clickable divs. When i click to third div for example i want to move to second page when dropdown menu changed based on which div select in the first page and showing third element from dropdown. When click to second div for example than move to second page and dropdown show his second element etc. Can someone show me the perfect way to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should include your code (divs) so that it could be easier to solve your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **location hash** for this.

Here say suppose this is your first page : (I used `<a>` tags instead of `div` to explain in simple way)

> First.html

```
<body>
    <a href="second.html#div1">Div1</a>
    <a href="second.html#div2">Div2</a>
    <a href="second.html#div3">Div3</a>
    <a href="second.html#div4">Div4</a>
    <a href="second.html#div5">Div5</a>
    <a href="second.html#div6">Div6</a>
</body>
```

*Note the href attribute in the above code.*

> Second.html

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="div1">Div 1</option>
    <option value="div2">Div 2</option>
    <option value="div3">Div 3</option>
    <option value="div4">Div 4</option>
    <option value="div5">Div 5</option>
    <option value="div6">Div 6</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if(hash!=""){
            document.getElementById("mySelect").value = hash.replace("#","");
        }
    })();
</script>
```

*Here you read the `window.location.hash` and sets the same in the `select`.*